# Rewrite sql sub to linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I'm really not even sure where to begin on how to convert this query into linq.

Started reading [here](http://linq101.nilzorblog.com/linq101-lambda.php) and looked for a few youtube videos but not really sure

Here is the query:

```
select 
o.ReplacementItemID,
o.ItemStatus,
o.Description,
i.ItemWarrantyID,
o.Id as OriginalItemId
from
(
    select 
        id,
        ItemStatus,
        Description,
        ItemWarrantyID,
        ReplacementItemID
    from item
    where ItemStatus = 'obso'   
)o
inner join Item i   
on o.ReplacementItemID = i.Id
```

Comment: Please never just post SQL and ask for conversion. At least show a class model so navigation properties and the multiplicity of associations are visible. Also, tell what type of LINQ you're targeting (to entities?), *and* show your own first efforts. They clarify more to us than you might think.

Comment: Also, your SQL is more complex than necessary. You don't need this subquery. Instead you can do: `from item o inner join item i on ... where o.ItemStatus = 'obso'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Christos provided a method chaining example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38405072/2607840), so here's a query syntax example:

```
var results = from o in (from x in item
                         where x.ItemStatus == "obso"
                         select new 
                         { 
                           x.Id,
                           x.ItemStatus,
                           x.Description,
                           x.ItemWarrantyId,
                           x.ReplacementItemId
                         })
             join i in item
               on o.ReplacementItemId equals i.ItemId
             select new 
             {
               o.ReplacementItemID,
               o.ItemStatus,
               o.Description,
               i.ItemWarrantyID,
               OriginalItemId = o.Id
             };
```

I'm partial to the query syntax for weird stuff like this, because it's typically easier to read. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
var result = items.Where(item => item.Status == 'obso')
                  .Select(item => new{
                         id,
                         ItemStatus,
                         Description,
                         ItemWarrantyID,
                         ReplacementItemID
                }).Join(items, 
                        itemA => itemA.ReplacementItemID, 
                        itemB => itemB.id,
                        (itemA, itemB) => new {
                            itemA.ReplacementItemID,
                            itemA.ItemStatus,
                            itemA.Description,
                            itemB.ItemWarrantyID,
                            OriginalItemId = itemA.Id
               });
```

In order you understand, the syntax, especially the `join`, please have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675(v=vs.110).aspx).